# ggplot2: fail replicating plot from 2 datasets

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I'm trying to replicate the last plot from this example:
https://www.r-bloggers.com/plotting-individual-observations-and-group-means-with-ggplot2/

I succeed when I use the same code and data from the example. However, if I'm trying it on my own it won't work.

My original data is a longformat:

```
> head(summpas)
id session paradigm  N    mean        sd       se min firstq median  thirdq  max
1  1      s1 baseline 20  831.00  692.7155 154.8959  95 326.50  585.5 1327.50 2433
2  1      s1    post1 20 1344.65 1261.5589 282.0931 107 315.25 1008.5 2105.00 4621
3  1      s1    post2 20 1058.05  856.6661 191.5564 105 144.50 1064.0 1915.25 2427
4  1      s1    post3 20 1318.00 1016.1804 227.2248  95 381.75 1289.5 1741.50 3688
6  1      s2 baseline 20 1058.20 1118.8923 250.1919  10 131.00  314.5 1984.25 3042
7  1      s2    post1 20 1909.65 1478.1206 330.5178  59 760.50 1465.0 2808.00 4602
```

Summarizing like stated in the example doesn't work for me:

```
> meansummpas <- summpas %>%
    group_by(session, paradigm) %>% 
    summarise(mean = mean(mean))
> meansummpas
mean
1 949.5366
```

So therefore I use:

```
library(plyr)
meansummpas <- ddply(summpas, c("session", "paradigm"), summarise, 
mean=mean(mean))
```

Now I try the plot:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(summpas, aes(x=paradigm, y=mean, group=id, colour=session)) + geom_line(aes(group=session), alpha=.3) + geom_line(data=meansummpas, alpha=.8, size=3)
```

But I get the error:

```
Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type 
tbl_df/tbl/data.frame. Defaulting to continuous.
Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (8): x, y, 
group, colour
```

What I have noticed is that the data from the example and my data are not exactly the same class (this also accounts for the unsummarized data):

```
class(gd)
[1] "grouped_df" "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
class(meansummpas)
[1] "data.frame"
```

Why do I get this error? What am I doing wrong? :)
Many thanks!!

Comment: `dplyr` doesn't return data.frames, but grouped data.frames, or tables, which ultimately can be interpreted as a data.frame. Why your approach with `group_by %>% summarise` doesn't group I cannot say. Please re-check that an error doesn't occur, or that you somehow skipped the middle line.

Comment: OK.I'm going to retry. but do you think this is the problem causing the error when I call my plot?

Comment: Could be; also try removing the `group` aesthetics from the main `ggplot` call. You are setting it explicitly in the first `geom_line`. You aren't in the 2nd, so it falls back to use `id` as grouping variable, which doesn't seem to exist for the data.frame `meansummpas`.

Comment: Yes, that seems to do something. Only now I get the error `geom_path: Each group consists of only one observation. Do you need to adjust
the group aesthetic?`. Therefore, I tried `ggplot(summpas, aes(x=paradigm, y=mean, colour=session)) + geom_line(aes(group=session), alpha=.3) + geom_line(data=meansummpas, group=1, alpha=.8, size=3)` But the plot doesn't make sense, it looks a bit like the first example plot from the link in my original post directly underneath the header "Repeated observations" (a lot of vertical lines). So there still seems to be something wrong with the grouping....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear what you are plotting, as you already seem to have summarised each paradigm/session.

It appears the issue with 'one observation per group' appears because your x-variable is categorial; this apparently implies a grouping.

But I did manage to get a plot that averages across all means, but I had to add row 8 and 9.

```
summpas <- read.table(text='id session paradigm  N    mean        sd       se min firstq median  thirdq  max
1  1      s1 baseline 20  831.00  692.7155 154.8959  95 326.50  585.5 1327.50 2433
2  1      s1    post1 20 1344.65 1261.5589 282.0931 107 315.25 1008.5 2105.00 4621
3  1      s1    post2 20 1058.05  856.6661 191.5564 105 144.50 1064.0 1915.25 2427
4  1      s1    post3 20 1318.00 1016.1804 227.2248  95 381.75 1289.5 1741.50 3688
6  1      s2 baseline 20 1058.20 1118.8923 250.1919  10 131.00  314.5 1984.25 3042
7  1      s2    post1 20 1909.65 1478.1206 330.5178  59 760.50 1465.0 2808.00 4602
8  1      s2    post2 20 1060.20 1118.8923 250.1919  10 131.00  314.5 1984.25 3042
9  1      s2    post3 20 1980.20 1118.8923 250.1919  10 131.00  314.5 1984.25 3042
', header=TRUE, as.is=TRUE)
ggplot(summpas, aes(x=paradigm, y=mean)) + geom_path(aes(colour=session, group=session)) +
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom='line', aes(group=NA))
```

Comment: The `summpas` data contains `id` on top of `paradigm` and `session`. `meansummpas` only contains `paradigm` and `session`. But, this almost gets me there.... I've adjusted the code to: `ggplot(summpas, aes(x=paradigm, y=mean)) + geom_path(aes(colour=session, group=session)) +
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom='line', aes(group=session))`. But Now I would like the summarizing line to be thicker than the rest of the lines...

Comment: Ok. I got my statisfactory plot using `ggplot(summpas, aes(x=paradigm, y=mean)) + geom_path(aes(colour=session, group=session), size=0.1) +
    stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom='line', aes(group=session, colour=session), size=1.5)`. Many thanks!!!!